# Choosing one point from each set of points in a map

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, geolocation, geometry

In a map, there are some ten thousand points scattered all over the place.

Every point belongs to some set of points, and there are about a hundred sets of points.

Some sets have a lot of points, whereas some sets have a few.

The problem is to partition the map into zones such that each zone (1) is a proper size(not too large, that is), and more importantly, (2) includes various points. By various, I mean that I am picking only one point from each set in each zone, and a zone contains (representative) points from, say, about 20 different sets.

What would be a proper algorithm to do this?

What immediately comes up on my mind is some variant of Minimum Spanning Tree algorithm, which starts from a point(node), and considers different edge weights(distances between points), and picks the nearest point that belongs to a set that we did not picked yet, and do this until the number of kinds of sets reaches 20, which makes a zone, and then start again from the nearest point outside the current zone.

However, I hope there is more effective algorithm to do this job, and I am already having difficulty in formalizing my design.

Comment: Could you add a simple image to clarify?

Comment: Sounds like a Voronoi(-ish) problem to me. Compute Voronoi partition for each set, then workout the intersections between Voronoi partitions for each set to get what you want. Although I am not too clear on what exactly you are looking for.